# Circular Progress Bar help, Swift Programming Language

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to make a small circular progress bar in swift,

This is what I have so far

```
 private var Timer:CGFloat = 100;

 override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) 
 {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    var StartAngle:CGFloat!
    var EndAngle:CGFloat!

    var circleTimer:UIBezierPath!

    StartAngle = CGFloat(M_PI * 1.5)
    EndAngle = StartAngle + CGFloat((M_PI * 2))

    var Progress:CGFloat = (EndAngle - StartAngle) * (Timer / 100) + StartAngle

    circleTimer.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(200, 200), radius: CGFloat(130), startAngle: StartAngle, endAngle: Progress, clockwise: true)

    Timer--;
}
```

I get this error when I run the App

"BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"

on this line

"circleTimer.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(200, 200), radius: CGFloat(130), startAngle: StartAngle, endAngle: Progress, clockwise: true)"

I'm fairly new to Swift (Programmed in other languages) and I can't seem to work it out.

Thanks
Luke

Comment: Until you get really good with Optionals, you should avoid adding a `!` suffix to your variables' types. That makes them "implicitly unwrapped optionals", which means that if you reference them and they contain nil, your app will crash. You should also avoid using `!` to force-unwrap optionals. That will also crash if the variable is nil. Instead use `if let`, `guard let`, or other ways of safely unwrapping them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not initialized `circleTimer` so `circleTimer` is nil.You should initialize it first than call

```
circleTimer.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(200, 200), radius: CGFloat(130), startAngle: StartAngle, endAngle: Progress, clockwise: true)
```

Intialize it with path

```
var circleTimer:UIBezierPath! = UIBezierPath()
```

Also write this in draw rect

```
 override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    var StartAngle:CGFloat!
    var EndAngle:CGFloat!

    var circleTimer:UIBezierPath! = UIBezierPath()
    StartAngle = CGFloat(M_PI * 1.5)
    EndAngle = StartAngle + CGFloat((M_PI * 2))

    var Progress:CGFloat = (EndAngle - StartAngle) * (Timer / 100) + StartAngle

     //Test this working fine
    //circleTimer.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(50, 50), radius: CGFloat(130), startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: Progress, clockwise: true)

    circleTimer.addArcWithCenter(CGPointMake(200, 200), radius: CGFloat(130), startAngle: StartAngle, endAngle: Progress, clockwise: true)

    Timer--;
    circleTimer.lineWidth = 20;
    UIColor.redColor().setStroke()
    circleTimer.stroke()
}
```

Comment: Awesome that worked! Don't mean to be a pain but how do I draw this to the scene, Ive added this so far                                       circleTimer.lineWidth = 15
UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
        
circleTimer.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50), radius: CGFloat(130), startAngle: StartAngle, endAngle: Progress, clockwise: true)
circleTimer.closePath()
circleTimer.stroke()

Comment: what do you man by `scene`.Do you want to draw in view or sprite kit?

Comment: @LukeBrandonFarrell edited answer have look change startAngle and oher code by yourself

Comment: Its on its way! Thank you :)

Comment: @LukeBrandonFarrell Please accept answer it will help others to find solution.